# how to get specific value from array of data coming from modal

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I am getting value from modal which contains array as well like this:

```
      <?php var_dump( $myaccount);?>
```

Result:

> array (size=1)   0 => 
>       object(stdClass)[28]
>
> public 'daysselected' => string '["Monday","Tuesday"]'
>
> public 'due' => string '["2017-06-12","2017-06-13"]'

I am trying to access Monday as single and similarly the date. How can i do so?

I am trying this:

```
 if(!empty($myaccount)){
     foreach($myaccount as $it){
           echo $it->daysselected[0];//i get '[' only
      }
}
```

Comment: this is because you daysselected is a string, you need an array

Comment: plz specify i also tried encode nd decode. bt was same

Comment: you should show how you get your `$myaccount` , is it possible to have arrays in it ?

Comment: you must convert your dayselected and due value to array because it is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($myaccount)){
  foreach($myaccount as $it){
    $days = str_replace(['\'', '"', '[', ']'],'', $it->daysselected );
    $daysSelected = explode(',', $days);
    echo $daysSelected[0];
  }
}
```

try to use this. But error is somewhere in getting of this value.

Answer (score 2):

If your array format like below :

```
$myaccount = array('daysselected' => '"Monday","Tuesday"',
                'due' => '"2017-06-12","2017-06-13"');

foreach ($myaccount as $key => $value) 
{
     $val = explode(',', $value);
     echo $val[0];
}
```

Please try this may be help you.

Comment: thnx ur solution is also best one

Answer (score 0):

//Try this code, it is cleaner and simpler:

```
if(!empty($myaccount)){
    foreach($myaccount as $it){
        eval('$ar = '.$it->daysselected.';');
        echo $ar[0];
    }
}
```